# How to use one function for multiple table-headers with different dataField

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have some functions that sort numbers in a table:

```
sortNumbers1(a,b,order){
   if (order === 'desc') {
     return Number(b.newScore) - Number(a.newScore);
    } else {
     return Number(a.newScore) - Number(b.newScore);
  }
} 

sortNumbers2(a,b,order){
   if (order === 'desc') {
     return Number(b.oldScore) - Number(a.oldScore);
    } else {
     return Number(a.oldScore) - Number(b.oldScore);
  }
}  
<BootstrapTable data={this.props.resData}>
   <TableHeaderColumn dataField="oldScore" dataSort={true} sortFunct={this.sortNumbers2}>       
     Old Score
   </TableHeaderColumn>
   <TableHeaderColumn dataField="newScore" dataSort={true} sortFunct={this.sortNumbers1}>
     New Score
   </TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

As you can see I have to define a sort function for every table-header (because they have different dataField), what if I have 100 table-header?

My question: Is there a way I can define only one function and use for all table headers (using parameter for example)

I have tried to use one function and pass a parameter for the datafield, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the field by which you want to sort the data inside parameter like this way:-

```
sortNumbersByField(a, b, order, field){
   if (order === 'desc') {
     return Number(b[field]) - Number(a[field]);
    } else {
     return Number(a[field]) - Number(b[field]);
  }
} 

<BootstrapTable data={this.props.resData}>
   <TableHeaderColumn dataField="oldScore" dataSort={true} sortFunct={this.sortNumbersByField}>       
     Old Score
   </TableHeaderColumn>
   <TableHeaderColumn dataField="newScore" dataSort={true} sortFunct={this.sortNumbersByField}>
     New Score
   </TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

At the time of calling function **sortNumbersByField** from **TableHeaderColumn** your code can define the column/field by which they want to sort the data.

Comment: This didn't work. How does it know what the parameter field is when calling the function without using parameters?

Comment: It actually worked when I changed the place of the parameters like this => sortNumbersByField(a, b, order, field){ //code...}

Comment: I will give best answer, but can you please tell me how does it know the value of the parameters? (or give me a link on this topic)

Comment: It depends that how you are calling the function sortNumbersByField. If function will receive correct parameter then it will sort the item on the basis of provided column.

Comment: @JohnDoeveto Please accept the answer if it works for you.